# Complie Error: Expected Function or Variable (using .Range())

Tags: vba, excel, range

So, all I'm trying to do is find the column name with "Severity" in it, then within that column, skip down 1 cell, and replace text "High" with 1, and the others with 2. The compile error points to the line with `.Range` where I set Rng = the offset variable.

Here's my VBA:

```
Sub Sev()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim aCell As Range, Rng As Range
    Dim col As Long, lRow As Long
    Dim colName As String

    '~~> Change this to the relevant sheet
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")

    With ws
        Set aCell = .Range("A1:N1").Find(What:="Severity", LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole, _
                    MatchCase:=False)

        '~~> If Found
        If Not aCell Is Nothing Then
            col = aCell.Column
            colName = Split(.Cells(, col).Address, "$")(1)

            lRow = .Range(colName & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

            '~~> This is your range
            lastCell = Range(col).End(xlDown).Select
            Set Rng = .Range(aCell.Offset(1, 0), lastCell).Select

            'Debug.Print Rng.Address
            cell = aCell.Offset(1, 0)
            For Each cell In Rng
                If (InStr(aCell.Value, "high")) > 0 Then
                    aCell.Value = 1
                Else
                    aCell.Value = 2
                End If
            Next cell


        '~~> If not found
        Else
            MsgBox "Nov Not Found"
        End If
    End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code after "this is your range" isn't defined correctly. I rewrote a couple lines in your code with my edits marked `PGCodeRider` in line. I think that accompmlishes what you want.

```
    Sub Sev()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim aCell As Range, Rng As Range
    Dim col As Long, lRow As Long
    Dim colName As String

    '~~> Change this to the relevant sheet
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")

    With ws
        Set aCell = .Range("A1:N1").Find(What:="Severity", LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole, _
                    MatchCase:=False)

        '~~> If Found
        If Not aCell Is Nothing Then
            col = aCell.Column
            colName = Split(.Cells(, col).Address, "$")(1)

            lRow = .Range(colName & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

            '~~> This is your range
            'lastCell = .Range(col).End(xlDown).Select 'pgCoderRider excluded
            Dim lastcell As Range: Set lastcell = .Cells(1, col) 'PGCODRIDER MODIFIED
            Set Rng = .Range(aCell.Offset(1, 0), lastcell) 'PGCODRIDER MODIFIED
            Rng.Select 'PGCODRIDER MODIFIED

            'Debug.Print Rng.Address
            cell = aCell.Offset(1, 0)
            For Each cell In Rng
                If (InStr(aCell.Value, "high")) > 0 Then
                    aCell.Value = 1
                Else
                    aCell.Value = 2
                End If
            Next cell


        '~~> If not found
        Else
            MsgBox "Nov Not Found"
        End If
    End With
    End Sub
```

Version 2:

```
Sub Sev2()
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim aCell As Range, Rng As Range
Dim col As Long, lRow As Long
Dim ColNumber As Integer

'~~> Change this to the relevant sheet
Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")

With ws
    Set aCell = .Range("A1:N1").Find(What:="Severity", LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole, _
                MatchCase:=False)

    '~~> If Found
    If Not aCell Is Nothing Then
        col = aCell.Column
        'colName = Split(.Cells(, col).Address, "$")(1) 'PGCodeRider not needed

        'lRow = .Range(colName & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row  'PGCOdeRider not needed

        '~~> This is your range
        'lastCell = .Range(col).End(xlDown).Select 'pgCoderRider excluded
        Dim lastcell As Range: Set lastcell = .Cells(Rows.Count, col).End(xlUp)  'PGCODRIDER MODIFIED
        Set Rng = .Range(aCell.Offset(1, 0), lastcell) 'PGCODRIDER MODIFIED
        'Rng.Select 'PGCODRIDER excludeded

        'Debug.Print Rng.Address
        'cell = aCell.Offset(1, 0)  'PGCODRIDER excludeded
        For Each cell In Rng.Cells
            If (InStr(aCell.Value, "high")) > 0 Then
                aCell.Value = 1
            Else
                aCell.Value = 2
            End If
        Next cell


    '~~> If not found
    Else
        MsgBox "Nov Not Found"
    End If
End With
End Sub
```

Comment: I no longer have the compile error. Thanks for the answer. However the for loop and the offset is not accomplishing what I want. It only changes the first cell, which is severity. It does nothing else. Any ideas?

Comment: I put a second version of code in @BeastlyBernardo. I think that does what you want. Try using the debugger tool more to isolate your errors, and make sure you understand the difference between setting integers and ranges, or combinations of the two i.e. cells(i+1,4) etc. That's where you were struggling. Good luck.